# No caching of .swf in Netsuite Suitelet

Tags: javascript, flash, netsuite

I have a Suitelet I built within Netsuite and it has an embedded flash object. Whenever the data for the .swf file changes I have to manually empty my browser cache to get the updated flash.

How can I force the browser not to cache the swf?

I have tried the following:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

and adding a random number to the end of the .swf source like so:

```
var time = new Date();
content += 'src="path/flash.swf?date='+time+'"';
```

Anyone have a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a random param to your Netsuite URL, not the swf url.  It gets cached by the browser page.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that and it didn't work.  I've since moved on to using a Javascript Slideshow.